# Not able to show , as a decimal separator in android softkeyboard

Tags: android

I am trying to show "," instead of "." as a decimal separator in android soft keyboard, but I am not able to achieve the same. Below is the code what i tried. 
...

```
DecimalFormat decFormat = (DecimalFormat) 
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=decFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
final String defaultSeperator=Character.toString(symbols.getDecimalSeparator());
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789" + defaultSeperator));
```

...

I also wrote class which is extending NumberKeyListener and used the same while setting keylistener for editext. But Still not working

```
public class DecimalDigitsInputFilter extends NumberKeyListener {

    private static final char[][] CHARACTERS = new char[][] {
            new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' },
            new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-' },
            new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ',' },
            new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '.', ',' },
    };

    private char[] mAccepted;
    private boolean mSign;
    private boolean mDecimal;

    private static final int SIGN = 1;
    private static final int DECIMAL = 2;

    private static DecimalDigitsInputFilter[] sInstance = new DecimalDigitsInputFilter[4];

    @Override
    protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
        return mAccepted;
    }

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter() {
        this(false, false);
    }

    public DecimalDigitsInputFilter(boolean sign, boolean decimal) {
        mSign = sign;
        mDecimal = decimal;

        int kind = (sign ? SIGN : 0) | (decimal ? DECIMAL : 0);
        mAccepted = CHARACTERS[kind];
    }

    public static DecimalDigitsInputFilter getInstance() {
        return getInstance(false, false);
    }

    public static DecimalDigitsInputFilter getInstance(boolean sign, boolean decimal) {
        int kind = (sign ? SIGN : 0) | (decimal ? DECIMAL : 0);

        if (sInstance[kind] != null)
            return sInstance[kind];

        sInstance[kind] = new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(sign, decimal);
        return sInstance[kind];
    }


    public static DecimalDigitsInputFilter getInstance(String accepted) {
        DecimalDigitsInputFilter dim = new DecimalDigitsInputFilter();

        dim.mAccepted = new char[accepted.length()];
        accepted.getChars(0, accepted.length(), dim.mAccepted, 0);

        return dim;
    }


    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
                | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
                | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED;
    }

}
```

And used above class like this

```
mWeightEditText.setKeyListener(new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(false, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not show a comma instead of the dot on the android soft keyboard.

You can extend the `NumberKeyListener` to accept ',' and '.' like this:

```
@Override
public int getInputType() {
   return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER 
          | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL 
          | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED;
}
```

Furthermore you can set a `TextWatcher` on the `EditText`, which replaced all '.' with ',' in `afterTextChanged()` method.

another way that you can try is the followings:
xml:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

in the code:

```
EditText input = new EditText(THE_CONTEXT);
input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

In this way, the Android will show the numbers' keyboard and allow the input of the comma and also if the user presses the '.' button nothing happens. (you can add '.' in xml and code so user be able to enter '.' too).

Comment: i tried all the approaches but still its not working. I edited my question please see the same.